# Dense set and measurable functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm here since I need help about giving an counterexample or proving a statement. It talks about lebesgue measure and dense sets.

"If two functions (f and g) coincide in a dense set, one of them is measurable if and only if the other function is measurable. "

I thought showing that there is a Vitali set that is dense in [0,1] and taking translates to get a dense, non-measurable subset D of R. Let f be the constant zero function, and let g be the indicator (characteristic) function of D, but I do now know how to do it rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a dense set (e.g. rationals) can have zero measure, so the condition says $f=g$ on a set that has potentially zero measure, so one has no control of the other.

For example we can take a non-measurable set $S$, let $f=\chi_S\cdot \chi_{{\mathbb R}-{\mathbb Q}}$,
so $f$ is not measurable, but $f=g$, where $g=0$, on the dense set ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Then the statement is false with that counterexample, g is measurable while f don't, thank you! I was beating around the bush